# bit conversion float to int

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

```
float FastInvSqrt(float x) {
  float xhalf = 0.5f * x;
  int i = *(int*)&x;          // evil bit-level floating-point hacking
  i = 0x5f3759df - (i >> 1);  // what the...?
  x = *(float*)&i;
  x = x*(1.5f-(xhalf*x*x));
  return x;
}
```

There are many places to read about this on the internet, but they all skip over the line:

```
int i = *(int*)&x;
```

Could somebody please explain it to me?

Comment: Type-punning or reinterpretation are good keywords for a search on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means: take the address of the variable `x` (whatever type it may be), cast that address to an `int` pointer then dereference that to get an `int` from that address.

Technically, I think it's undefined behaviour but it works fine in many implementations. I suspect the author didn't really care that much, based on the non-readability of the code :-) They could at least have documented the method, even if with only a URL.

The cast after the integer manipulation line (the one you've so elegantly described with WTF) is similar as it goes from `int` back to `float`.